# Using function inside constriant block

Tags: constraints, system-verilog, verification

I am trying to use a function inside constraint block. Randomization happens but the constraints are not being met.  I have verified that the function works as expected outside the constraint block. The function uses only function arguments and not any other class members.

```
local rand      logic [6:0] [3:0] [9:0] coeff_mult;

constraint prods_are_multiples {
     foreach(coeff_mult[i]) {
           get_real(coeff_mult[i][3]) == (-1 * get_real(coeff_mult[i][0]));
           get_real(coeff_mult[i][2]) == (-1 * get_real(coeff_mult[i][1]));
           get_real(coeff_mult[i][0]) == (3 * get_real(coeff_mult[i][1]));
     }
 }

 function automatic shortreal get_real(input [9:0] val);
                shortreal sign;
                bit [9:0] magnitude;
                sign = -1**(val[9]);
                magnitude = ({10{val[9]}} ^ val[9:0]) + val[9];
                get_real = sign * (magnitude[9:3] + magnitude[2] * 0.5 + magnitude[1] * 0.25 + magnitude[0] * 0.125);                
 endfunction
```

I came across a similar [post](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/function-call-system-verilog-constraint-vcs), but it didnt solve my problem.

Is there anything wrong with the code? If not, is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [post](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/function-call-system-verilog-constraint-vcs) you reference explains the reasoning. The inputs to your function get their random values chosen before calling the function in the constraint. So there are effectively no constraints on `coeff_mult` before evaluating the equality constraints.

Also, the LRM does not allow expressions of non-integral values in constraints, technically, although some tools allow limited cases.

The best strategy for randomizing real numbers is doing everything with scaled integral values, then converting the resulting values to real (or sign/magnitude) in `post_randomize()`.

Comment: Even though if the solver choses random values before calling the function, then also ultimately the constraint should be satisfied and if not satisfied, then solver will choose another set of random values. Right?

Comment: No, the constraint solver only has one iteration. Otherwise it's too easy to get into an infinite loop.

Comment: @dave_59 I tired different things to make the function work, but ended up replacing the function with integers in constraint block and put the function in post_randomize().

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example of your kind of function usage with use of additional random variable. I have checked this with ~10 different seeds and I have also posted constraint results with 1 particular seed.

```
typedef bit [7:0] tabc;

class t;
  rand bit [3:0] a, b;
  rand tabc ca;

  // Original Constraint : get_b(b) == get_a(a) + 1;
  constraint c {
    ca == get_b(b);
    get_a(a) ==  ca - 1;
  }

  function tabc get_a (input bit[3:0] a);
    return (tabc'(a + 15));
  endfunction

  function tabc get_b (input bit[3:0] b);
    return (tabc'(b + 10));
  endfunction
endclass

program temp();
  t t1 = new();

  initial
  begin
    repeat (10) begin
      t1.randomize();
      $display("t1.a - %0d", t1.a);
      $display("t1.b - %0d", t1.b);
    end
  end
endprogram

// Results - 
t1.a - 7
t1.b - 13
t1.a - 2
t1.b - 8
t1.a - 5
t1.b - 11
t1.a - 4
t1.b - 10
t1.a - 0
t1.b - 6
t1.a - 8
t1.b - 14
t1.a - 9
t1.b - 15
t1.a - 6
t1.b - 12
t1.a - 0
t1.b - 6
t1.a - 5
t1.b - 11
```

I am not quite sure of how this one is different than your method. However I am thinking that without having any random variable in constraints, the solver might have considered as no constraint for any variable and hence it didn't try to solve constraint before the solution.

I tried to insert temporary variable, in order to force solver to look at constraints first.

I am not sure how much correct my explanation is, but atleast it worked for me for some time. You can check it and try to run it with more seeds, before adapting it into your solution.

Comment: I tried this first :
`local rand      logic [6:0] [3:0] [9:0] coeff_mult;
rand logic [9:0] c0,c3;
 constraint prods_are_multiples {
     foreach(coeff_mult[i]) {
           c0 == get_real(coeff_mult[i][0]);
           c3 ==  get_real(coeff_mult[i][3]);
            c3 == (-1 * c0);
     }
 }`

It didnt work, I think maybe because of foreach sharing the c0,c3 for each coeff_mult. I tried without foreach too for a single coeff_mult[0], but it didnt work either. Maybe it has something to do with the real numbers as Dave said.

Comment: Can you try without foreach now and also try with `c0 == func; func == c1; c1 == ~c0 + 1;`